# How to get specific webservice method stub code in axis2 web service

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am trying to call the axis2 webservice methods using java. so that i have created the stub code using WSDL2Java bat file which is present in axis2 bin folder. By using WSDL2Java batch file i got number of webservice method code and this works fine.

Now my question is How can we get the specific webservice method stub code to call that from java main method?

else

Is there any other way to call the axis2 webservice using java Main class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to call from main() method. Seems like you already have the client stubs generated. All you need to know is how to use them. Follow [this tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/12/13/invoking-web-services-using-apache-axis2.html) and ask follow up questions.

You can create clients using other APIs as well and in general there are [multiple ways of accessing a web service in J2SE and JEE/J2EE environment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-javaclient/).